# Struggling with email regular expression; can you help?

Tags: javascript, regex, email

OK, so I know it's impossible to fully validate email addresses with RegEx, and I would just try and email it and have a user click on a validation link. However, this is part of an a-level project, and I get extra complexity points for doing it, so I was wondering if you could help me out. I'm trying to write an email validating regular expression, that follows the following rules:

*An email address must consist of a local part and a domain part separated by an @ symbol (x40) with a combined length of no more than 256 characters.*

***Local Part:***

*A non-quoted local part may consist of (a-z), (A-Z), numeric (0-9) and the following characters:* !#$%&'*+-/=?^`_`{`|}~ *CHECK*

*Dots may also be present in the local part, but can not be the first nor last character, nor adjacent to another dot (.) ALMOST CHECK, DOT CAN STILL BE LAST*

*Maximum length of the local part is 64 characters. MIGHT IGNORE - NOT CHECK*

***Domain Part:***

*Domain part consists of dot separated labels of 1 to 63 characters each, up to a maximum total length of 255 characters (including dot delimiters). CHECK*

*Domain labels must begin and end with an alpha (a-z) (A-Z) or numeric (0-9)  character and may include hyphens (-).  In addition, the TLD (last label) must contain at least one alpha character or hyphen (not all numeric), and be at least two characters. - CHECK*

In caps is how far along I am, in terms of meeting the goal. The main problem I'm having is making sure a dot cannot be the last character in the local part of the domain. Here's my RegEx so far:

/^[A-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]([A-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]|(.(?!.))){0,62}[A-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]?@([A-z0-9-]{1,63}.){1,126}[A-z-]{2,63}$/

Edit: there should be backticks at the start and end of the grey section.

Comment: What in the world is an "a-level project" and what are "complexity points"? Is this some sort of school project? If so, shouldn't you be figuring it out on your own?

Comment: College project, and yes I should but it's bugging the hell out of me.

Comment: Oh and A-Levels are the british equivalent of AP, assuming you're from the US.

Comment: Dear God, you get extra marks for making it complicated??? No wonder the UK economy is heading south.

Comment: Presumably he gets more points for matching a _specification_ that's more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-](\.?[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9]([A-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-z0-9])?\.)+([A-z][A-z0-9]+|[A-z0-9]+[A-z]|([A-z0-9]+[A-z-]+[A-z0-9]?)+[A-z0-9]+)$/
```

Done it :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) complaint RegEx would be:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

You should probably take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html though.

Comment: Actually, both the above RegEx and the simplified examples on the linked page allow consecutive dots. (e.g. hel..lo@email.com), will match when it is in fact invalid. I'm still stuck.

Comment: Maybe consecutive dots is part of the protocol.